# how to use greater than equal to in between two objects in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have:

`<% @offers.each do |offer|%>`

`if offer.totalAmount >= cart.total`

I am new in rails.Why this comparison operator is not working.I have the value in the two objects.

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: @john - that correct syntax. What's the error u r getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% @offers.each do |offer|%>
<% if (offer.totalAmount >= cart.total) %>
```

Let me know its work or not? `cart` object comes from where? is that offers table's attribute?

If `cart` is associated table with `offer` then try this

```
<% if (offer.totalAmount >= offer.cart.total) %>
```